Minimp3 Rust - "slice::get_unchecked_mut requires that the index is within the slice"
While developing an audio-centered application, I came across an issue with the minimp3/minimp3_fixed crate when using it to decode mp3 files. The error/output looks like this:
Decoding MP3 File.
Iterating through PCM data.
thread 'main' panicked at library/core/src/panicking.rs:220:5:
unsafe precondition(s) violated: slice::get_unchecked_mut requires that the index is within the slice
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
thread caused non-unwinding panic. aborting

The error occurs when trying to call the decoder.next_frame() method.
Here's my code:

pub(crate) fn decode_mp3_file(file_path: &str) -> Vec<f32> {

    println!("Decoding MP3 File.");

    let mut decoder = Decoder::new(File::open(&file_path).unwrap());

    let mut output_data: Vec<f32> = Vec::new();

    println!("Iterating through PCM data.");

    loop {

        match decoder.next_frame() { // ERROR HERE
            Ok(Frame { data, sample_rate, channels, .. }) => {
                println!("Reading PCM data: {} samples, {} Hz, {} channels", data.len(), sample_rate, channels);
                for sample in data.iter() {
                    output_data.push(*sample as f32 / 32767.0); // Convert i16 to f32 PCM.
                }
            },
            Err(Error::Eof) => {
                println!("Reached end of file.");
                break;
            },
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("Error decoding MP3 frame: {:?}", e);
                break;
            },
        }

    }

    output_data

}

I previously used the crate creak, but that broke after updating cargo, so I decided that was a sign to revamp the mp3 loading to something more dedicated. This is important as it's evidence that there is nothing wrong with the file_path parameter, but rather with minimp3 directly.
I also tried switching to minimp3_fixed, which I am continuing to use, but had the exact same error.
What's truly strange is that I have looked over my code so many times, and not once found any difference from the example code in the minimp3 and minimp3_fixed examples and docs on docs.rs, crates.io, and github.
What's also strange is that this is not a return from the error check? I thought an error with next_frame() would run the Err branch I put there with "Error decoding MP3 frame".

The output shows that this is a panic and not a returned Result::Err. The message in particular indicates that what the library is attempting what would cause undefined behavior. This indicates a bug and should be reported to the library maintainers if not already.

@kmdreko I'll report that right now.

Actually, this seems to be already reported - https://github.com/germangb/minimp3-rs/issues/42.
